# Replace colon and a comma dinammicaly in a string

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a main string dynamically created from other strings.
The various strings are separated within the main string by commas.

```
for (var item in fieldsValue) {
    editorValue += fieldsValue[item] + ',';
}
```

- first string
- is equal to second string
- another string

Result:

**first string, is equal to second string, another string**

However, when a string is followed by a colon ':' I intended to remove the ':' and the comma following

- first string:
- is equal to second string
- another string

Result

**first string:,  is equal to second string, another string**

I managed to successfully remove ':'

```
editorValue.replace(/:/g,"");
```

How to remove the comma that follows?

The result I want:

**first string is equal to second string, another string**

Comment: `editorValue.replace(/:,/g,"");` ?

Comment: Thanks BenG. it works perfectly. If you want to put your response in 'Answer', I mark as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add the comma after the colon:-

```
editorValue.replace(/:,/g,"");
```